# How do I convert a 3D point cloud (.ply) into a mesh (with faces and vertices)?

Tags: python, mesh, point-clouds, delaunay, trimesh

I have a 3-D point cloud file with 1 million points that I need to convert into a mesh file in trimesh. The ultimate goal here is to take a point cloud and determine if that point cloud is convex or concave (trimesh allows me to do that once i convert the cloud into a mesh). I'm open to other libraries to solve this.

I've tried Delaunay triangulation using scipy, I just can't seem to convert my pointcloud into the right format so that it can be read by trimesh.

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np
import trimesh
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay


pointcloud = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh("pointcloud.ply")
points = np.array(pointcloud.points)
triangle_mesh = Delaunay(points)
#  How do i include triangle_mesh from Delaunay triangulation into processing the mesh file?
mesh = trimesh.load("pointcloud.ply")
print(trimesh.convex.is_convex(mesh))
```

Error

```
geometry::TriangleMesh appears to be a geometry::PointCloud (only contains vertices, but no triangles).
geometry::TriangleMesh with 1390073 points and 0 triangles.
expected = (faces.shape[0], faces.shape[1] * 2)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: I believe i'm approaching this  wrong. Perhaps Delaunay triangulation can not do this very obviously.

Comment: Based on `open3d-python==0.0.7.0`:

1. `o3d.PointCloud` does not have `points` but `vertices`. So `np.array(pointcloud.points)` should not work.

2. Unlike `open3d`, `trimesh` won't load a PointCloud without faces. You can artificially add a single face and save again so that you can load it with trimesh (either by loading with `open3d`, adding, saving - or directly editing the file and adding the fake face).

Answer (score 30):

Open3d 0.8.0.0 has now implemented the [rolling ball pivoting algorithm](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.html#open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_ball_pivoting) to reconstruct a mesh from a point cloud.

I solved the problem of generating a trimesh from a point cloud using the following:

```
import open3d as o3d
import trimesh
import numpy as np

pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("pointcloud.ply")
pcd.estimate_normals()

# estimate radius for rolling ball
distances = pcd.compute_nearest_neighbor_distance()
avg_dist = np.mean(distances)
radius = 1.5 * avg_dist   

mesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_ball_pivoting(
           pcd,
           o3d.utility.DoubleVector([radius, radius * 2]))

# create the triangular mesh with the vertices and faces from open3d
tri_mesh = trimesh.Trimesh(np.asarray(mesh.vertices), np.asarray(mesh.triangles),
                          vertex_normals=np.asarray(mesh.vertex_normals))

trimesh.convex.is_convex(tri_mesh)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just inquiring what this line of code actually does? It calls the function with point cloud, as `pcd`, but what does the double vector section mean? -  `o3d.utility.DoubleVector([radius, radius * 2]))`

```
mesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_ball_pivoting(
           pcd, o3d.utility.DoubleVector([radius, radius * 2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

To save the mesh after following answer of
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57971745/6394769  use trimesh export options:

```
trimesh.exchange.export.export_mesh(tri_mesh, 'output file path.ply .obj etc..')
```

https://trimsh.org/trimesh.exchange.ply.html

If you want to keep colours in trimesh, make this change:

```
tri_mesh = trimesh.Trimesh(....., vertex_colors = np.asarray(mesh.vertex_colors))
```

https://trimsh.org/trimesh.base.html

Alternatively you can directly save mesh using open3d itself:

`o3d.io.write_triangle_mesh('file path .ply or .obj etc..', mesh, write_ascii=True (if needed as text and not binary file), compressed=False, print_progress=False)`

Mesh colour also saved here if present inside mesh variable.

http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.io.write_point_cloud.html#open3d.io.write_point_cloud

Comment: How can you display the mesh using open3d?

Comment: # First compute normals for 3d rendering
mesh.compute_vertex_normals()
# Then display using draw geometries
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([mesh])